# version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.6.8, need exactly 8.6

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Tried to check similar questions, but still have problems. 
I have downloaded, compiled and installed Tcl/Tk 8.6.8 and included test programs run OK, so as far as I can see the installation is OK (running Linux Red Hat 7.2).

I have an old C++ program with the following code that fails in the "Tc_EvalFile" command, giving the message "version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.6.8, need exactly 8.6":

```
char *tclFile = getenv("TCL_SOURCE"); //a tkcon.tcl file
if (tclFile != (char *)NULL) {
   if (Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
      ... }  // no error
   if (Tk_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR) {
      ... }  // no error
   if (Tcl_EvalFile(interp, tclFile) == TCL_ERROR) {
      cout << " " << Tcl_GetStringResult(interp) << endl; //returns "version conflict...."
      return TCL_ERROR;
   }
}
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH, TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY and TCL_SOURCE are set.
Have tried to set "8.6" in init.tcl/tk.tcl, but then I get "Can't find a usable tk.tcl".
The code earlier ran OK on Solaris with Tcl/Tk version 8.4.

Comment: This is not really a complete enough snippet. Check that you are calling `Tcl_FindExecutable()` before `Tcl_CreateInterp()`.If this is older C++ code it might not be making this call but it became mandatory in Tcl 8.5.something.

Comment: There is no way this code could have compiled: look at getenv("TCL_SOURCE) with no end of string terminator in the code? How could that have ever compiled?

Comment: Added Tcl_FindExecutable() before Tcl_CreateInterp(), but got the same error message. (And updated the code example above with a " after TCL_SOURCE, it is already in my code :-)

Comment: Where does `TK_LIBRARY` point to? Is it the same, expected directory containing `tk.tcl` ...? I am a little irritated by the fact that the error message says: "[...] need exactly 8.6." ... shouldn't that be a patch level (8.6.?)?

Comment: Yes, TK_LIBRARY points to <my tcl tk install dir>/lib/tk8.6/ , where tk.tcl is.

Comment: Sounds like the binary for libtk.so isn't matching the script files that support it.

Comment: Ahh - the it was the tkcon.tcl file that caused the "version conflict" error! I tested with one of the test files from the installation and it ran OK. The tkcon.tcl file had a "require -exact Tk $tcl_version".